# Have an arc path follow a rotating line

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, path, rotation

With C#, WPF I have this working entirely, except for this line. The angle is dynamic. I would like an arc to follow the angle, on the periphery of the radius, whether 1 degree or 360.

I cannot post pictures yet. So, if you can imagine a clock at noon (0 degree). As the second hand moves to 12:15 (90 degrees), there is a red arc following the outline of the clock from 0 to 90 degrees. Of course as the hand moves to 12:30 (180 degrees) the red line follows from 0 to 180 degrees.

I've been trying to figure this out for a week now. I do not know how binding works, so please be gentle with your explanation!

Comment: Shall this also work for angles larger than 180 degrees?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code for a possible Solution (no binding at all):

[image: Rotating line]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="530" Width="943">
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="200">
            <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Black">
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-50" Y="-50" />
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            </Ellipse>
            <Canvas>
                <Line X2="0" Y2="-50" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="2,1" />
                <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="-5,-55">
                                <PolyLineSegment Points="-0,-50 -5,-45" />
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas>
                <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,-50">
                                <ArcSegment
                                    IsLargeArc="False"
                                    Size="50, 50"
                                    Point="50, 0"
                                    SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Explanation:
There are 4 elements on the canvas:
- A basic black ellipse as background
- The red arc 
- The red arrow
- Dashed black line on current position

In order to play around (and integrate Binding, more on that later), you can adjust the Angle of the RotateTransform (which rotates the dashed line and the small arrow) and the Point Property of the ArgSegment ("0,-50" = 0°, "50,0" = 90°, "0,50"=180° , "-50,0" = 270°). If the Angle is higher than 180, you also need to set the IsLargeArc Property to "True"

Binding:
You could directly bind the rotation to the disered Angle
In order to set the correct End-Point of the arc, you could create a ValueConverter which converts the angle to the corresponding point (use sinus/cosinus)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Philip, as I stated, I have everything else done. What I don't understand is how to make the xaml interact with user entered data. I don't think what you provided will work with what I have. Not everything in my code is being used as of yet. This is kind of my test until I get it nailed down. using System;

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using HelixToolkit.Wpf;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }              

        public void geometry()
        {
            canvas4.Children.Clear();
            double one, two, three, four, ang, ang2, x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4, Rads;
            if (double.TryParse(txtOne.Text, out one))
                if (double.TryParse(txtTwo.Text, out two))
                    if (double.TryParse(txtThree.Text, out three))
                        if (double.TryParse(txtFour.Text, out four))
                            if (double.TryParse(txtAngle.Text, out ang))
                                if (double.TryParse(txtAngle.Text, out ang2))


            if (double.TryParse(txtAngle.Text, out ang))
                if (double.TryParse(txtAngle.Text, out ang2))
                {
                    RotateTransform ans2 = new RotateTransform();
                    ans2.Angle = ang2;
                    ans2.CenterX = 180;
                    ans2.CenterY = 180;

                    if (ang2 < 0)
                    {
                        ang2 = (360 + ang);
                    }

                    Rads = Math.PI * ang / 180;

                    x1 = Math.Sin(Rads) * 50;
                    y1 = Math.Cos(Rads) * 50;
                    x2 = Math.Sin(Rads) * 160;
                    y2 = Math.Cos(Rads) * 160;
                    x3 = Math.Sin(Rads) * 50;
                    y3 = Math.Cos(Rads) * 50;
                    x4 = Math.Sin(Rads) * 160;
                    y4 = Math.Cos(Rads) * 160;

                    Line lineW = new Line();
                    lineW.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    lineW.StrokeThickness = 1.5;
                    lineW.X1 = 180;
                    lineW.Y1 = 15;
                    lineW.X2 = 180;
                    lineW.Y2 = 340;
                    lineW.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    lineW.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                    lineW.RenderTransform = ans2;
                    canvas4.Children.Add(lineW);

                    Line lineY = new Line();
                    lineY.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    lineY.StrokeThickness = 1.5;
                    lineY.X1 = 180;
                    lineY.Y1 = 20;
                    lineY.X2 = 180;
                    lineY.Y2 = 340;
                    lineY.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    lineY.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;              
                    canvas4.Children.Add(lineY);

                    Line lineZ = new Line();
                    lineZ.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    lineZ.StrokeThickness = 1.5;
                    lineZ.X1 = 20;
                    lineZ.Y1 = 180;
                    lineZ.X2 = 340;
                    lineZ.Y2 = 180;
                    lineZ.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    lineZ.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;                   
                    canvas4.Children.Add(lineZ);

                    Ellipse ell6 = new Ellipse();
                    ell6.Width = 10;
                    ell6.Height = 10;
                    ell6.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    ell6.Fill = Brushes.LimeGreen;              

                    TranslateTransform ell66 = new TranslateTransform(175+x2, 175-y2);
                    ell6.RenderTransform = ell66;                  
                    canvas4.Children.Add(ell6);

                    Ellipse ell7 = new Ellipse();
                    ell7.Width = 10;
                    ell7.Height = 10;
                    ell7.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    ell7.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
                    TranslateTransform ell77 = new TranslateTransform(175 + x1,175- y1);
                    ell7.RenderTransform = ell77;
                    canvas4.Children.Add(ell7);

                    Ellipse ell8 = new Ellipse();
                    ell8.Width = 10;
                    ell8.Height = 10;
                    ell8.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    ell8.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
                    TranslateTransform ell88 = new TranslateTransform(175 - x2, 175 + y2);
                    ell8.RenderTransform = ell88;
                    canvas4.Children.Add(ell8);

                    Ellipse ell9 = new Ellipse();
                    ell9.Width = 10;
                    ell9.Height = 10;
                    ell9.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                    ell9.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
                    TranslateTransform ell99 = new TranslateTransform(175 - x1, 175 + y1);
                    ell9.RenderTransform = ell99;
                    canvas4.Children.Add(ell9);

                    PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
                    PathFigure figure = new PathFigure();
                    figure.StartPoint = new Point(180, 20);
                    figure.Segments.Add(new ArcSegment(new Point(180 + x2, 180 - y2), new Size(320, 320), ang2, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true));                    


                    pathGeometry.Figures.Add(figure);
                    Path path = new Path();
                    path.Data = pathGeometry;
                    //path.Fill = Brushes.Pink;
                    path.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
                    canvas4.Children.Add(path);                    
                }
        }



        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {           
            geometry();           
        }

        }
    }
```